# How to get an active link from current url

Tags: jquery

I have this code to get an active link, but it adds the class `current` to all `li` not just the current.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.ribbon a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).closest('li').addClass('current_yes');
});
```

This is my html menu code:

```
<!-- Responsive menu -->
<div class="ribbon">
<div class="rmm style">

<ul>
<li>
<a href="./index.html">HOME</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">PROJECTS</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="">IKEA - NORWAY</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">FASTEC - SWEDEN</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="./clients.html">CLIENTS</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="">IKEA</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">FASTEC</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">CONTACT US</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">WEBSHOP</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">ADMIN</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="">STAFF</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="">DOCUMENTS</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide as an example with your html-markup?

Comment: seems to be fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/07208pwg/3/

Comment: empiric. Here you go. What happens whit my code is that every link exept the current link gets the current_yes class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a much easier way, because with jQuery, you can select elements by its attributes.

```
$(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.ribbon a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('current_yes');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.ribbon a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href')  ===  window.location.pathname) {
      $(this).addClass('current_yes');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working for me. I added the menu html code in the first post. I want the class in the li.